# Handle Xmpp group in objc

Tags: xmppframework, multiuserchat

I have created room with XMPPFramework in objc .. I created it successfully but when I m going to offline that time room was destroy. I also no idea where I should place invite function  to add user in group (room). please sort out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's destroyed probably because you created a temporary room, which is destroyed after last occupant left it.

XMPP rooms can be persistent vs. temporary

Here is a XEP-0045 config on how to handle it

```
<field
    label='Make Room Persistent?'
    type='boolean'
    var='muc#roomconfig_persistentroom'>
  <value>1</value>
</field>
```

https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#registrar-formtype-owner